# Cambiar los colores con plot en R

Tags: r

Tengo el siguiente objeto, que representa toda la cuadrícula UTM 10x10 km que cubre España, con dos variables que indican el número de muestreos realizados en cada cuadrícula y el número total de ejemplares capturados en esos muestreos:

```
class(resultado_primavera_laea)
[1] "sf"         "data.frame"

head(resultado_primavera_laea)
  utmcode                                                                                                    geom capturas
1  FT4050 -828763.8, -818818.0, -819665.9, -829611.7, -828763.8, 191290.4, 190460.0, 180473.9, 181303.5, 191290.4        0
2  FT4040 -829611.7, -819665.9, -820512.0, -830457.8, -829611.7, 181303.5, 180473.9, 170487.6, 171316.2, 181303.5        0
3  FT4030 -830457.8, -820512.0, -821356.1, -831301.9, -830457.8, 171316.2, 170487.6, 160501.0, 161328.8, 171316.2        0
4  FT5030 -820512.0, -810566.1, -811410.2, -821356.1, -820512.0, 170487.6, 169658.7, 159673.0, 160501.0, 170487.6        0
5  FT6030 -810566.1, -800620.0, -801464.2, -811410.2, -810566.1, 169658.7, 168829.5, 158844.8, 159673.0, 169658.7        0
6  FT2020 -851193.0, -841247.6, -842089.8, -852035.3, -851193.0, 162983.6, 162156.3, 152167.7, 152994.2, 162983.6        0
  muestreos
1         0
2         0
3         0
4         0
5         0
6         0
```

He representado el objeto mediante este código,

```
laea = st_crs("+proj=laea +lat_0=28 +lon_0=-5")
resultado_primavera_laea <- st_transform(resultado_primavera, laea)
g <- st_graticule(resultado_primavera_laea)
plot(resultado_primavera_laea['muestreos'], graticule = TRUE, axes = TRUE, 
lwd = 0.001, key.pos = 4, key.width = lcm(1.3), border = 'white', breaks = 'jenks')
```

Y el resultado es este
[image: mapa]

Creo que mejoraría la visibilidad del mapa si utilizase otra rampa de color (por ejemplo en rojos, de muy clarito a más intenso) y pudiese representar el fondo de la `graticule` en gris o azul muy claro. ¿Alguien sabe orientarme para hacerlo? Muchas gracias

Comment: Algunas preguntas para poder ayudarte. 1. ¿Qué librerías tienes cargadas para poder hacer el mapa? 2. ¿A qué clase pertenece `resultado_primavera_laea['muestreos']`? Esto porque `plot` es una función genérica y dependiendo el método (que depende de la clase del objeto que le pasas como datos) podría depender la manera de cambiarle los colores. 3. ¿Podrías incluir un ejemplo mínimo reproducible?

Comment: Edito la pregunta original, para ayudar con la respuesta